# In javascript, after a function name has been pointed somewhere else, is there any way to get to that unnamed function?

Tags: javascript, function

So I understand that a functions name is just a pointer to the actual function.

```
function justAPointer() { //do something }
```

And I can change that pointer name :

```
justAPointer = 'oops';
```

Now that function STILL exists but is there any way to still reach it?

Comment: Might be a bit late on my answer. At the very least, I hope it completes what the others have said. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function only still exists if something refers to it. Otherwise it's garbage to be collected, just like anything else your code may allocate.

If you create an object:

```
var obj = { hello: "world" };
```

and then reassign "obj" to something else:

```
obj = 22;
```

then that object is similarly garbage. Of course, and also similarly, if a copy of the reference were made, it'd still be around:

```
var obj = { hello: "world" };
var copy = obj;
obj = 22;
```

then clearly "copy" would refer to the object still. Functions really aren't any different.

*edit* — SLaks points out in a comment that there are some ways in which a reference to a function can be deposited in certain places in such a way as to ensure the continued "alive-ness" of an object (or a function), even though access to the object (or function) is lost. An example is the `setTimeout()` function. A function object passed in to that API will remain alive until the timer goes off, but if your code retains no other links to the function, you can't get a reference back out of the runtime system. There are (or used to be) similar situations with objects that might be associated with DOM elements. That caused (and may possibly still cause; I'm pretty risk-averse) problems in that the DOM garbage collector in some browsers (guess) didn't know how to free up JavaScript-allocated storage.

Comment: Actually, that's not quite true.  If I pass it to `setInterval()`, it still exists, yet there is no way to access it.

Comment: Ah!  That makes sense!  I was stepping through it in Chrome and I could still see the function when I assigned something else to it beforehand.

Comment: hmm, I seem to have been a consistent 30 seconds behind you in extending my answer.  Upvoted for speed :)

Answer (score 2):

Not if there are no other references to it.

In fact if it has no other references and its state isn't being used (IE it is not a closure function), this statement

> Now that function STILL exists

is not necessarily valid.  The function may be garbage collected and removed from memory.

If you want to reclaim a variable name and maintain a reference to the function, just alias it.

```
var foo = function(){...}

var bar = foo;

foo = "new value";

bar() //runs the original foo
```

Comment: Ya, I tried that.   
Weird thing though is that when I stepped 'watched' bar even after foo had been changed, the debugger (Chrome) still showed function foo() {}  ... probably just how Chrome does it I guess, but I thought it was strange.

Comment: thats because you used a named function expression. When you use the `function foo(){}` form it sets the function name internally to `foo`, whereas `var foo = function(){}` creates an anonymous function and points foo to it.  But the internal name of the function is irrelevant in looking it up.  You need an external reference.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing that up ... so even though the internal name is still named 'foo' , since the real 'foo' is pointing somewhere else, its still unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

A function in JavaScript is an object. In other words, by declaring a function, you are creating an instance of a Function object.

Below are different ways of declaring a function:

```
//function statement
function x (a, b) { return a + b;  }

//function expression, this will store an anonymous function into a variable
var y = function (a, b) { return a + b;  };

//Function constructor 
var z = new Function ("a", "b", "return a + b;"); // avoid this form, it will prevent certain optimizations from the browser's JS engine because of the strings (this is just an example)
```

Take note of the code below. It replaces the reference to `x`, `y` and `z` to an instance of a String object. This means that there will be 4 references to `"potato"` and 0 reference for `x`, `y` and `z`.

```
var potato = "potato";
x = potato:
y = potato;
z = potato;
```

When a JavaScript object **has 0 reference** to it, it will be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

---

**References**

- [Mozilla Developer Network - Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)
- [Mozilla Developer Network - Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)